# Nintex Conditional Rules According to a Choice Field

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

in my list i have these cloumns:

1- a choice  drop-down List (Item1, Item2,.....)

2- Date-and-Time filed

the List date and time field need to be compared with the current date and time according to the choice from the drop-down list

for Item1,  the entered DATE should be >= 2 days from current date

for Item 2, the entered TIME should be >= 2 hours from current time

for any other item, no need for any validation

Comment: What is not working? You are talking about Nintex Workflow; you need help designing the workflow?

Comment: Dear Abbas, it is not about workflow design, im only looking for this function to calculate the time difference in hours between the current time and another Date/time field